# Can I tweak a page's appearance using Google Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firebug

When I'm working on a web page layout, I often use Firefox and Firebug to tweak the CSS until it looks right, then modify my style sheet to match.

Right now, I'm trying to fix something that looks fine in other browsers but wrong in Google Chrome. I have pulled up Chrome's Developer Tools, and can inspect the computed style, but don't see a way to edit values and see the results on my page.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For CSS, for example, you double click on the property in the right pane. For HTML, right click on an element and select "Edit as HTML".

Comment: Ah - I see. I was looking at the "computed style" part, which you can't edit. Below that are the various rules, which you can. Thanks!

Comment: Oh wow - this actually gives me a ton of info, like associated javascript events. And the collapsible sections are cool, too.

Comment: In the Metric section you also can directly edit position, padding, margin etc.